ERC20InsufficientAllowance in ERC20Wrapper Contract
I got this error:
ERC20InsufficientAllowance
Parameters:
{
 "spender": {
  "value": "0xb31BA5cDC07A2EaFAF77c95294fd4aE27D04E9CA",
  "documentation": "Address that may be allowed to operate on tokens without being their owner."
 },
 "allowance": {
  "value": "0",
  "documentation": "Amount of tokens a `spender` is allowed to operate with."
 },
 "needed": {
  "value": "10",
  "documentation": "Minimum amount required to perform a transfer."
 }
}
You may want to cautiously increase the gas limit if the transaction went out of gas.

My Contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.23;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Wrapper.sol";

contract xBTCWrapper is ERC20, ERC20Wrapper {
    IERC20 public  _underlying;

    constructor(IERC20 underlyingToken)
        ERC20("Wrapped xBTC", "wxBTC")
        ERC20Wrapper(underlyingToken)
    { 
        _underlying = underlyingToken;
    }

    function getUnderlyingBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return _underlying.balanceOf(_msgSender());
    }

    function decimals() public view virtual override(ERC20Wrapper, ERC20) returns (uint8) {
        return 18;
    }
}


Note I've tried to send it with only transfer but this time I got ERC20InsufficentBalance Error, which is weird because I've tokens.
using SafeERC20.transfer instead of transferFrom
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.23;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Wrapper.sol";

contract xBTCWrapper is ERC20, ERC20Wrapper {
    IERC20 public  _underlying;

    constructor(IERC20 underlyingToken)
        ERC20("Wrapped xBTC", "wxBTC")
        ERC20Wrapper(underlyingToken)
    { 
        _underlying = underlyingToken;
    }

    function depositFor(address account, uint256 value) public virtual override(ERC20Wrapper) returns (bool) {
        address sender = _msgSender();
        if (sender == address(this)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidSender(address(this));
        }
        if (account == address(this)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidReceiver(account);
        }
        SafeERC20.safeTransfer(_underlying, address(this), value);
        _mint(account, value);
        return true;
    }

    function getUnderlyingBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return _underlying.balanceOf(_msgSender());
    }

    function decimals() public view virtual override(ERC20Wrapper, ERC20) returns (uint8) {
        return 18;
    }
}



The other error:
ERC20InsufficientBalance
Parameters:
{
 "sender": {
  "value": "0x7C4e30a43ecC4d3231b5B07ed082329020D141F3",
  "documentation": "Address whose tokens are being transferred."
 },
 "balance": {
  "value": "0",
  "documentation": "Current balance for the interacting account."
 },
 "needed": {
  "value": "10",
  "documentation": "Minimum amount required to perform a transfer."
 }
}
You may want to cautiously increase the gas limit if the transaction went out of gas.


Did you have balance of ERC20 token before transfer? Check it by function balanceOf(sender), you can get balance by constructor or  provide mint function for owner/admin. Btw, please provide all full steps you did run through, it will help everyone can understand your concept.

If you're asking to check the balanceOf _underlying.balanceOf(sender) yes I did and it was showing the balance of the user.

You should use transferFrom. The "ERC20InsufficientAllowance" is because you need to approve the contract as spender in a previous transaction.
